# On algebraically closed field

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Prove that $K$ is a algebraically closed field iff there are not exist algebraic extensions over $K$ of degree $>1$

Can anyone tell me a hint to solve the problem?

Comment: Is it not obvious?

Comment: Do you imply "Algebraically closed field" iff "The field has no proper algebraic extension"
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field

Comment: Jack surely means that if you **really** understand what's going on (definitions, basic facts, etc.), your question has a very trivial answer.

Comment: @DonAntonio: I think that trivial answer you told is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraically_closed_field#The_field_has_no_proper_algebraic_extension

Comment: Indeed so, @user109250...look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know (hopefully) that if $\;f(x)\in\Bbb K[x]\;$ is irreducible and has degree greater than zero, then $\;\Bbb F:=\Bbb K[x]\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ is an extension field of $\;\Bbb K\;$ with a root of $\;f(x)\;$ in it, namely $\;\alpha:=x+\langle f(x)\rangle\;$ , and the extension's degree is $\;\deg f(x)\;$.

Suppose now that $\;\Bbb K[x]\;$ is algebraic closed and let $\;f(x)\in\Bbb K[x]\;$ be irreducible of degree more than zero. But then $\;f(x)\;$ has a root in $\;\Bbb K[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\cong \Bbb K[x]\;$ , which means $\;\deg f(x)=1\;$...

I leave it to you the other direction, which is more boring than the above one.